# Designing a 100 W 150 kHz sine wave oscillator

Tags: rf, oscillator, inductive

**Problem:** I need to design an oscillator that is capable of producing a sine wave at 150 kHz using 100 W (50 V and 2 A).

This signal will be used to drive a pretty heft induction coil for resonant charging. I've poked around some forums and it's recommended to use a sine wave over square wave for these operations. The problem is that I am having trouble coming up with a sufficient circuit design for such a problem.

This circuit needs to eventually be mounted on a PCB. There's an onboard MCU as well if that poses assistance in the circuit.

Thanks in advance for any help. Will gladly reply if any more details are needed

*Note:* Supplied 50 V is DC

Comment: Is that 50V RMS? Or peak to peak? And do you have 50V available already?

Comment: @mkeith The 50V DC is indeed readily available, at up to 3 amps.

Comment: That's basically a 150kHz sine generator followed by an appropriate amplifier, both of these standard kit in EMI testing. Since the frequency is fixed, the amplifier doesn't need to be flat across the spectrum, that makes things a lot easier. Whether it's worth designing your own depends on the number of units you want to build.

Comment: To a first approximation, all you have to do is generate a PWM sine wave and feed it to an H bridge. Note: if you really need 50V sine wave output, you will need a higher DC voltage (50 * sqrt(2) + a little bit for headroom).

Comment: Wireless charging is never driven like that. Efficiency in generating a sine the "linear" way is  so low while, on the other hand, the complexity of doing it "switch mode" is not really needed. What is usually done is to get the coil resonating with some capacitance and square drive them by some ZVS scheme. I'd suggest to scouting for some reputable source application note, Infineon, Onsemi, Wurth or many others, there are plenty out there.

Comment: I Googled ‘induction heater schematic ‘ and got plenty of hits. Most are for higher powers, but the basis is the same. You can buy them out of China cheaply, so I’d think twice about rolling my own.

Comment: Look at the Baxandall class D oscillator, it produces a fairly good sine wave without wasting much energy.

Comment: An induction heater and an induction charger are not the same thing. I believe (but I am not sure about this) that the power factor of the charger primary coil will be much higher than the power factor of the primary coil of the induction heater. Of course this applies only when the secondary is consuming power. The open circuit power factor will be terrible.